# Voting tool with CouchDB and conflict issues

Tags: angularjs, json, couchdb

I'm building a very small app where the user chooses a category, then a logo from said category and submits a form.

The document with the categories and logos is a JSON, and I have a bit of experience with CouchDB, but I get the feeling that such an app is a revision conflict magnet, as it'd be difficult to keep track of different users using at the same time and trying to update the document with the same revision ID.

I haven't been able to find some code or idea dealing with this issue.

Here's how my JSON looks like:

```
$scope.categories = [
      {
        name: 'DIY',
        logos : [
            {
                url:'img/...1.png',
                votes:0
            },
            {
                url:'img/...2.png',
                votes:0             
            }   
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Food',
        logos : [
            {
                url:'img/...1.png',
                votes:0
            },
            {
                url:'img/...2.png',
                votes:0
            },
...
```

Any idea on how to deal with such an issue?

Here's a [live test version of the app](http://cccctanger.com/christian/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to understand the design of your app. If I were designing this, I think I would generate a new CouchDb document when the form is submitted to record each vote. This would avoid updating any shared document and any risk of conflicts. Showing the results would then be a map/reduce query on the "vote" documents.